# Adding words to dictionary in TeXMaker

Tags: texmaker, dictionaries

I am using Texmaker 4.4.1 for LaTex. Text editor  performs a spell check automatically and underlines the wrong spelled words. How can I add new words to the dictionary with which it makes a comparison

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7):

In TeXMaker, choose Options -> Configure TeXMaker -> Editor.

The following windows will appear

[image]

In the textbox named "Spelling dictionary" you can find the name of the file containing the dictionary you are using.

Open this file in TeXMaker (or in any text editor) and add the words you like. Note that you must respect the alphanumeric ordering.

Comment: Please I try to add some words in the dictionary, I should make (/M, /MS, /DSMG, \S)?

Comment: @M.A basically, these letters are rules for prefix/suffix adding/modification of the words. If you have to add basic nouns in english you can type `my_noun/S` to add the plural. There is also the `'s` suffix with the M letter, so if you want add those to : `my_noun/SM`. Plenty of other suffix/prefix are coded in the `.aff` file, next to the `.dic` file. D is used for 'ed' kind suffix and G for 'ing' suffix. More info here: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/developers/how-tos/editing-the-spell-checking-dictionaries